# Combine/Concat multiple Evals inside DataList

Tags: c#, datalist, itemtemplate, datalistitem

I am using `DataList` and in one column I need to display two fields combined, I need the column display as `Name1(Name2)`

Here is my code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlistDetails" runat="server" DataKeyField="KeyID"
              RepeatColumns="3" Width="100%" 
              AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="Wheat" CaptionAlign="Top">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text= '<%#Eval("Name1")%(<%#Eval("Name2") %>)' /> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

The same is done in my `GridView` and its showing the result,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tweak your existing code to:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlistDetails" runat="server" DataKeyField="KeyID"
              RepeatColumns="3" Width="100%" 
              AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="Wheat" CaptionAlign="Top">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name1") + "(" +  Eval("Name2") + ")"%>' /> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this code

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format(
      "return {0} % {1}", 
       Eval("Name1"), 
       Eval("Name2")) %>' /> 

    </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a easiest way to do this same thing...

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name1").ToString() +", "+ Eval("Name2").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
```

.

```
<%#Eval("Name1").ToString() +", "+ Eval("Name2").ToString() %>
```

Here both objects are converted into string the concatenate them.

Comment: Yea, i also found this is simplest form to this.

Comment: Welcome.. neeraj-bisht